# WP7 DatePicker, TimePicker data binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datetime, data-binding, windows-phone-7.1

I'm building an application that needs to display and accept dates from my model ( which is retrieved from a database).  The model exposes a property called EntryTime:

```
 private DateTime entryTime;

[Column]
public DateTime EntryTime
{
    get { return entryTime;  }
    set
    {
        if (entryTime != value)
        {
            this.NotifyPropertyChanging("EntryTime");
            entryTime = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("EntryTime");
        }
    }
}
```

I have both a DatePicker and a TimePicker on my page and want to bind them both to the EntryTime.  I tried binding them just by binding the values but that didn't work:

```
    <toolkit:DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="151,6,0,0" x:Name="dateCurrent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Value="{Binding CurrentEntry.EntryDate}" />
    <toolkit:TimePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="313,6,0,0" Name="timeCurrent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="{Binding CurrentEntry.EntryDate}" Width="137" />
```

I'm relatively new to Silverlight so i'm not sure what i can do to just bind the time picker to the time for EntryDate and the DatePicker to the date for EntryDate.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding should work.  If you can elaborate on exactly what issue you're having that would be great.  The one thing I did notice that you were missing was the "TwoWay" Mode on your binding:

```xml
    <toolkit:DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="151,6,0,0" 
              x:Name="dateCurrent" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top"  
              Width="175" 
              Value="{Binding CurrentEntry.EntryDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <toolkit:TimePicker 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="313,6,0,0" 
              Name="timeCurrent" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Value="{Binding CurrentEntry.EntryDate, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="137" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem. Try to bind DatePicker to **DateTime?** not to **DateTime**